# Looping <td> depends on rowCount inside while

Tags: php, loops, pdo

I need loop td inside while fetch.

> td loop depends on rowCount variable from the first query.

```
<?php include'../db/dbConnect.php';
$_GET['tb'];
$t=$_GET['tb'];
$q=$con->prepare("desc $t");
$q->execute();
$h=$q->rowCount(); ?>
<table>
<tr>
    <?php while($r=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){ ?>

<th><?php echo $r[0];?></th>

    <?php } ?>
</tr>

<?php
$q=$con->prepare("select*from $t");
$q->execute();

          while($r=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
$d=$r[0];
?>
<tr>   
 <td><?php echo $d;?></td> 
</tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Above code give result :

```
col1   col2   col3 
12    
13       
14
```

But i need the result with :

```
col1     col2   col3 
12       vala      x
13       valb      y
14       valc      z
```

It must give td depends on rowCount variable.

I tried before to loop td by using while, but this i'm not get the logic.

I appreciate some logic or advice of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fetching multiple rows:

```php
$r=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)
```

But then only displaying the first column:

```php
$d=$r[0];
<tr>   
    <td><?php echo $d;?></td> 
</tr>
```

Try something like this:

```php
while( $r=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) )
{
    ?>
    <tr>
    <?php
        foreach( $r as $colIdx => $column )
        {
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $column;?></td>
            <?php
        }
    <?
    </tr>
    <?php 
}
```

NB. Not tested; but you get the idea.